# How to request user permission to read a file in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-oauth, add-on

I am working on a Google Apps Script add-on for Sheets which has been verified for the drive.file scope. At one point I need to read the parent folder of the current spreadsheet so I can create files in it. Is it possible to do this without having the drive.readonly scope? Could I request access from the user solely to that folder? If so, how would I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps this will help:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization?hl=en#manual_authorization_scopes_for_sheets_docs_slides_and_forms

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the:
 `. . . googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
scope, then you don't need to also have the `drive.readonly` scope.  The add-on can get access to a particular folder by having the user use the Google file/folder picker.  So, the user needs to use the picker before the code runs to access that folder.  The add-on can not get access to a folder without the user authorizing permission.

- Enable the Google Picker API in the Google Cloud Platform project
- Get the developer key for the picker
- Load the Google picker into HTML in a script tag:    `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script><!-- This is for the file picker -   -->`
- Integrate your client side code with the picker code.  E.g. Your button to open the picker
- Configure the picker settings.  Use a mime type for folders:  `view.setMode(google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST).setMimeTypes('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');`
- Handle the returned value from the picker to get the folder ID and save the user preference if needed.

See:
https://developers.google.com/picker/docs